# ffmpeg creates empty file

Tags: php, ffmpeg, mp3, mp4

I'm trying to convert an mp4 video into an mp3 audio file using ffmpeg and PHP. I have the ffmpeg shared library installed in `C:/wamp/www/ffmpeg`.

Here is my code:

```
$cmd = 'C:/wamp/www/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe -i C:/wamp/www/blog/test.mp4 -vn -acodec copy C:/wamp/www/blog/test.mp3';
exec($cmd, $output);
```

The problem is that while it creates `test.mp3`, it is a completely empty file. Also, `$output` is empty as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can also do: ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -vn -c:a libmp3lame -f mp3 output.mp3 , cause "-acodec copy : will copy your audio stream ,but if your video dnt have a mp3 stream ,but aac stream , you will not get a mp3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by using this command instead:

```
C:/wamp/www/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe -i C:/wamp/www/blog/test.mp4 C:/wamp/www/blog/test.mp3
```